# What is ITurnContext.TurnState used for and what is its lifetime?

Tags: botframework

I'd like to use **ITurnContext.TurnState** to store some state that is not part of a dialog conversation.  I am trying to store the Follow-on state for the new Multiturn QnA Maker so it will be available to fetch if a follow-on choice is made for a QnA question that has follow-on prompts.  What is the lifecycle scope of this **TurnState**?

I could create a State Property Accessor and store it in private conversation state but that's a lot of work compared to adding a single property to the **TurnState's** collection if that property will be persisted and available next turn.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid you will have to use an `IStatePropertyAccessor<TurnState>` or use your own logic to persist your values. Using the TurnState the way you described, the values will only be available for the lifetime of the turn. A turn is generally referred as sending an Activity to the bot so it does equal an API request. Your TurnState values will be `null` on subsequent requests.